# Extract integers from string and add them in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to extract the integers from string and add them.

Ex :

```
String s="ab34yuj789km2";
```

I should get the output of integers from it as 825 ( i.e., 34 + 789 + 2 = 825 )

Comment: `javasript` !===== `java`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216065/how-to-extract-numeric-values-from-input-string-in-java

Comment: @Guy I would recommend this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216123/982149 over the accepted answer in the question you linked.

Comment: @Fildor So do I, but its up to the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way, by using String.split:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="ab34yuj789km2";
    int total = 0;
    for(String numString : s.split("[^0-9]+")) {
        if(!numString.isEmpty()) {
            total += Integer.parseInt(numString);
        }
    }
    // Print the result
    System.out.println("Total = " + total);
}
```

Note the pattern `"[^0-9]+"` is a regular expression. It matches one or more characters that are not decimal numbers. There is also a pattern `\d` for decimal numbers.

Comment: It worked. @Patrick

Comment: glad to hear that @pb_! Please don't forget to mark an Accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the number from string by using regex.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ab34yuj789km2");
    Integer sum = 0;
    while(matcher.find()) {
       sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    }
```

Comment: This too worked @Anh Pham

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8:

```
String str = "ab34yuj789km2";
int sum = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+"))
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
    .sum();
```