# How to get particular value from string and add to other

Tags: java

```
String first  = "01 apple & 3 orange & 22 choco";  
String second = "11 apple & 02 orange & 03 choco";
```

I want count of choco from each string and sum of them.

22+03 = 25

Comment: Just split the string and use map. Hope that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to extract numeric values from input string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216065/how-to-extract-numeric-values-from-input-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Stream API may be used here to build a map of fruit / number and calculate the total values:

1. Create stream of the `first` and `second` strings
2. Split each line by "\s*&*\s*" (an ampersand surrounded with optional whitespaces) and use `flatMap` to get `Stream<String>` stream of pairs "Number Fruit"
3. Split each pair string to `String[]` by "\s+"
4. Build a map `Map<String, Integer>` using `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.summingInt`, counting the totals per fruit
5. Get the total value for `"choco"`

```java
Integer chocoTotal = Stream.of(first, second) // Stream<String> initial strings
    .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s*&\\s*"))) // split each line and get Stream<String>
    .map(pair -> pair.split("\\s+")) // split pairs, Stream<String[]>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        p -> p[1], 
        Collectors.summingInt(p -> Integer.parseInt(p[0]))
    ))
    .get("choco"); // get the total

System.out.println("Total: " + chocoTotal);
```

Output

```
Total: 25
```

---

Also, a pattern may be created with a regular expression to detect the pairs of `Integer Fruit` format

```java
Pattern pairPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+(\\w+)");
Integer sum2 = Stream.of(first, second)
    .flatMap(str -> pairPattern.matcher(str).results()) // Stream<MatchResult>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        mr -> mr.group(2), 
        Collectors.summingInt(mr -> Integer.parseInt(mr.group(1)))
    ))
    .get("choco");
    System.out.println("Total = " + sum2);
```

Output:

```
Total: 25
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is by splitting the string at every space and use the value at the 7th position:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    String first  = "01 apple & 3 orange & 22 choco";  
    String second = "11 apple & 02 orange & 03 choco";
    
    String[] choco1 = first.split(" ");
    String[] choco2 = second.split(" ");
    
    System.out.println("Total: " + (Integer.parseInt(choco1[6]) + Integer.parseInt(choco2[6])));
}
```

The **output**:

```
Total: 25
```